# Lyx BibTeX error: illegal, another \bibstyle command

Tags: lyx

I'm getting the above error when including multiple child documents in a main document. Each child document has a BibTeX Bibliography. The child documents on their own don't have errors. And if I include only a single child document in the main document there is no error. However as soon as multiple child documents are included, the error arises.

What am I doing wrong?

Attached is a screenshot of the BibTeX log:
[image: Attached is a screenshot of the LaTeX log]

MWE:

```
    \lyxformat 544
\begin_document
\begin_header
\save_transient_properties true
\origin unavailable
\textclass report
\use_default_options true
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language english
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman "default" "default"
\font_sans "default" "default"
\font_typewriter "default" "default"
\font_math "auto" "auto"
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100 100
\font_tt_scale 100 100
\use_microtype false
\use_dash_ligatures true
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize default
\use_geometry false
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine basic
\cite_engine_type default
\biblio_style plain
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 1
\use_minted 0
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\is_math_indent 0
\math_numbering_side default
\quotes_style english
\dynamic_quotes 0
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset CommandInset include
LatexCommand include
filename "Chapter1/Chapter1_test.lyx"

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset CommandInset include
LatexCommand include
filename "Chapter2/Chapter2_test.lyx"

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

That's the master document and as soon as I include any 2 child documents with Bibliographies, I get the error.

Comment: Hi Oliver and welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please post a MWE of your Problem that illustrates the setup?

Comment: Hi @TobiBS, I've inlcluded the text from the master document however not sure how I go about including Child documents and Bibliographies to the example in order to illustrate the problem

Comment: sorry but the BibLaTeX file alone will not be enough to find your issue. One needs a whole minimal example including an instruction for the compile steps to reproduce the issue.